# Jackson: Serialize Pojos selectively using @JsonView annotation

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, json-view

I'm pretty new to `@JsonView` and trying to use it for the first time in our application. We use Springboot 2.7.17.

By default if I don't set `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION = FALSE` then @JsonView has no affect, hence I set it and now I get only fields which are annotated with @JsonView.

This is not my intention since we have many different controllers and Pojos and it's not practical to go over each controller and add the proper @JsonView annotation.

So my question is: Is there a way to make it finer in the controller?? meaning by default serialize all fields of a pojo unless a field is annotated with @JsonView so in that case it would drill down a pojo and only serialize its properties if they are annotated with the same JsonView?

I just find it hard to get this mechanism into a server which wasn't coded with this approach to begin with and now we are interested to get it only in new controllers.

Thank!